# How to add packageSourceMapping targeting pattern and version in NuGet.Config

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

In an `C#` based project, I am using preview packages are are hosting on a `nuget.cloudsmith.io` not `nuget.org`. The production packages are hosted on nuget.org.

I want to define rules in my `Nuget.config` file to restore preview packages from `nuget.cloudsmith.io` but others from `nuget.org`

So any package id that starts with `PackagePrefix.` and the version contains `-preview-` should be downloaded from `cloudsmith.io`. Any other package should be downloaded from nuget.org.

For example, the package `PackagePrefix.SomeProject` with version `2.5.0` will be downloaded from nuget.org. But, The package `PackagePrefix.SomeOtherProject` with version `2.6.0-preview-5` will be downloaded from `cloudsmith.io`.

Here is what I have done. But I can't find a way to target package-id + version pattern. I tried to map using `<package pattern="PackagePrefix.*" version="*-preview-*" />` but this does not seems to be working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="cloudsmith.io" value="https://nuget.cloudsmith.io/PackagePrefix/preview/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>

  <packageSourceMapping>
    <!-- key value for <packageSource> should match key values from <packageSources> element -->
    <packageSource key="nuget.org">
      <package pattern="*" />
    </packageSource>
    <packageSource key="cloudsmith.io">
      <package pattern="PackagePrefix.*" version="*-preview-*" />
    </packageSource>
  </packageSourceMapping>

</configuration>
```

Here is the warning I get when trying to build a project

```
warning NU1507: There are 2 package sources defined in your configuration. When using central package management, please map your package sources with package source mapping (https://aka.ms/nuget-package-source-mapping) or specify a single package source. The following sources are defined: nuget.org, cloudsmith.io
```

How can I map a package using package id and package version to a specific source?

Comment: Is your problem with allowedVersions not solved?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#constraining-upgrades-to-allowed-versions,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config

Comment: The nuget.config reference documentation doesn't list `version` as part of the schema: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#package-source-mapping-section. I wouldn't expect this to be related to the NU1507 though. My guess is that the nuget.config you added this config to isn't being used in the restore. The nuget.config should be in the same directory as your `.sln` file, or a parent directory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#config-file-locations-and-uses

Comment: also, if you're restoring on Linux, then `Nuget.config` is not a correct casing for nuget.config. It should be `nuget.config`, `NuGet.config`, or `NuGet.Config`. Linux filesystems are (by default) case-sensitive.

Comment: @zivkan thank you. I think you are saying the file name should be `nuget.config` to work on all environments. But I am still not sure how to specify mapping based on the package id + version where the previews are pulled from `cloudsmith.io` and the rest from `nuget.org`

Comment: there's no way to say that specific versions of a package come from 1 source, and other versions come from another source.